# How to check value in edit text while entering text in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a edit text field named as mobile and password and Scenario is that when app launch it appears with error text ,what I want when enter a text in respective field and after completing editing text check with value if correct then move else show error in that field.

**code:-**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver m_oOtpReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {// creating broadcast to receive otp sent by server from Inbox...
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {// on receive method to read OTP sent by server
        checkFieldsForEmpty(true);// check whether edit text is empty or not

    }
};
private TextWatcher m_oTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {// making object of TextWathcher class
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {// when text change in Edit tEXT

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkFieldsForEmpty(false);// CHECK LOGIN BUTTON DISABLED AND ENABED
    }
};

/*This method check Edit text is empty or not*/
public void checkFieldsForEmpty(boolean fromBroadcast) {// this method check Edit text is empty or not

    s_szMobileNumber = m_InputMobile.getText().toString().trim();// get mobile number from edit Text
    s_szPassword = m_InputPassword.getText().toString().trim();// get password from edit text

    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
        // if mobile number and password are Emoty
        if (s_szMobileNumber != null && s_szMobileNumber.length() > 7 && s_szMobileNumber.length() < 15) {// check if mobile and password is empty ..
            if (s_szPassword.length() >= 4 && s_szPassword.length() <= 8) {
                m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(true);// make Login button disabled

                m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 80, 147));// set background color on eabled
                m_LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {// onclick listener on Login Button
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        postLoginDataToServer();

                    }
                });
            } else {
                    if (!fromBroadcast) {

                        m_InputPassword.setError("Password must be between 4 to 8 characters long");
                    }
                m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);// make login button enabled
                m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button
            }

        } else {
                if (!fromBroadcast) {
                    m_InputMobile.setError("Mobile number must be between 7 to 15 characters long");
                }

            m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);// make login button enabled
            m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button

        }

    } else {
        try {
            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No Internet Connection Available", getApplicationContext());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);
        m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where the boolean "fromBroadcast" is either initialised or gets it's state from to know whether that is what you need to check before setting the error message on the textView. From what I have read I would assume you don't need to use an if statement to check "fromBroadcast". The code should work without it. If you are starting the app with an error message and you dont want the error msg then you should check s_szPassword instead of m_InputPassword for input and you can initialise s_szPassword to contain the correct word first so the error msg is not there at the start.